# phpmyadmin, I have a problem in mysql database column with the constraint DEFAULT it's not working

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

how it has been configured:
COLUMN valid_untill:

valid_untill `DATETIME DEFAULT DATE_ADD(`Referral_date` + interval 3 day)

COLUMN valid_untill is based on column referring_date:

referring_date it is also constraint DEFAULT: DEFAULT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP).

when I insert a specific insert to the column it's working fine add 3 days to the date
there is no bad planning overall column and table operate great but,

but when I did not give both columns a data,
column referring_date gets the CURRENT TIMESTAMP(as it should) and the column doesn't get any column but zeros.
(doesn't show null)

I want the column to get the current TIMESTAMP from the column referring_date and add 3 days to the current TIMESTAMP 3 days

Comment: Is one of these a typo  Referral_date` and referring_date ?

Comment: From your description we can surmise that current_timestamp is not assigned to referring date until after the insert..so a trigger may be appropriate..

Answer (score 0):

if your question is if the two columns have the same type, yes their type is DATETIME.